# Proctect my app next js or nodejs type script API

Tags: next.js

first of all, thanks by the support!

I'm just getting to know if there is an npm package or a tool in order to protect my next js or node js (typescript) app...

For example, the use of an obfuscate tool ? or
license key like keygen SAAS app - https://keygen.sh/ ?

Can someone give me an idea?

Thanks in advance
Shintaro

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could help

https://github.com/fmiras/next-pkg

Get an exe of next js app.

Have someone tried?

Thanks
Shintaro

Answer (score 0):

I have use 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg

And made pkg app.js and it will create 3 binary files
I execute on this way ./app-so

Now I want to deploy to heroku...
can someone have an idea?

Thanks
Carlos Vieira